# buttons can't made draggables by jQuery UI draggable()

Tags: jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-draggable

The `jQUery UI draggables` sample named `Default` says that:

> Enable draggable functionality on any DOM element.

But I'm not able to make them work on `button`s elements.

I modified the `Default` sample to look like this:

I just changed the div element to a button one with `type="button"`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
    <style>
    #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</button>

<div class="demo-description">
<p>Enable draggable functionality on any DOM element. Move the draggable object by clicking on it with the mouse and dragging it anywhere within the viewport.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How I can make the draggables functionality work on a button element?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Using `cancel: false` seems to work for me.

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        cancel: false
    });
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/wzaJH/)

I guess without the cancel only the default click event of the button fires and with [cancel](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) you prevent the default click event.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: However, it can't throw the droppables events since it isn't considered effectively as a draggable per se. Have you a solution to this?

Comment: What do you mean by "droppables events"? If I drop it on a `droppable` widget it is recognized like any other element. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/wzaJH/1/)

Comment: No problem. If you have any further issues feel free to open another question. Perhaps provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ;)

Comment: Sure, thanks! I use jsfiddle for the code samples (see my other answers or questions) but right now I'm behind a veryyy low connection (believe me, a dial-up @28kbps) and jsfiddle takes to long for me, so that tool for now is banned :D hahaha

Comment: +1 as it resolved my problem. But I did not understand the working since as per api it should be used to restrict an element from being dragged. My case I just needed the cancel property with any value, I tried all values like - false, true, "anmol", "" and all worked like a charm, the button was moving. Again HOW is my curiosity :)